# Getting a ressource ID, from a WC_Order_Item_Product/Order

Tags: plugins, php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I have been trying to figure out how i get the ressource on a WC-order, from the product line data, but i seem not to be able to figure this out in WC 3.0+ - pre that it was pretty easy.
I have looked at both the booking meta data, the order meta data, and everything else i can think of, but still unable to find what im looking for.
I have 1 Product with the ID 194 and that product have 2 ressources - and im looking to find the resource in the order line.

Code:

```
$order = new WC_Order((int)$order_id);
$orderLine = array_values($order->get_items())[0];
```

Plugins:

- Updated WooCommerce
- Updated WooCommerce-Booking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found a "solution" even though it's not as good as i hoped - or atleast not as good as the way it was done pre 3.0.

```
$iOrderID = $_POST['iOrderID'];
$aBookingQuery = new WP_Query( 
    array( 
        'post_parent'       => (int)$iOrderID,
        'post_type'         => 'wc_booking',
        'posts_per_page'    => 1 
        )
    );
 = $aBookingQuery->posts[0]->ID;
$iBookingRessoureceID = get_post_meta($iBookingID)['_booking_resource_id'][0];
```

this gives you the ressource ID of said booked product.

Answer (score 1):

For existing orders, you need to use the `wc_get_order()` function.

Comment: Sadly this does not help me, either way im left behind with a WC_Order_Item_Product Object, that i cant get any usefull information out of (Ressource ID, of the purchase) - but in the future i will make sure to use wc_get_order(), when dealing with existing orders